# Calcium carbonate and hydrogen phosphate producing calcium phosphate, carbon dioxide, and water

Tags: stoichiometry

How does the balanced reaction look for these compounds? I found that phosphoric acid instead of hydrogen phosphate creates a much easier problem, but the teacher said hydrogen phosphate and I can't seem to balance it.

Comment: Phosphoric acid *is* hydrogen phosphate! If there's a distinction to be made, one can argue that hydrogen phosphate is pure $\ce{H_3PO_4}$, while phosphoric acid is an aqueous solution of hydrogen phosphate (i.e. $\ce{H_3PO_{4\ (aq)}}$). The stoichiometry of the reactions should be the same though.

Comment: Oh, now I see you mean *mono*hydrogen phosphate, $\ce{HPO_4^{2-}}$.

Comment: Oh! That explains why I am so mixed up. I'm sure you are correct in thinking that I'm supposed to use regular H3PO4

Comment: Well, you can actually also write a reaction for $\ce{HPO_4^{2-}}$. Perhaps it might help you to explicitly include a spectator counterion, such as $\ce{Na^+}$, so you can analyse the reaction $\ce{Na_2HPO_4 + CaCO_3 -> ...}$ and then remove it later

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that your teacher meant to say phosphoric acid ($\ce{H3PO4}$) rather than the hydrogen phosphate anion ($\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$) so lets go with that.

$$\ce{ 3CaCO3 + 2H3PO4 -> Ca3(PO4)2 + 3CO2 + 3H2O}$$

In reality the carbon dioxide and water would exist in an equilibrium state with carbonic acid, $\ce{H2CO3}$:

$$\ce{ H2CO3 (aq) <=> H2O (l) + CO2(aq)}$$